# Just stuck on a python code.Hope someone can help me out.I know i am asking a silly question but i am stuck for 2 hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

**Here is the code for finding average of three numbers** 
It is giving some errors

```
num1 , num2 , num3 = int (input ( "enter three numbers ")).split(",")  
print ( " average of three numbers is ({}+{}+{})/3 ").format( num1 , num2 , num3 )
```

Comment: What errors? Be specific please and [post them](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54494709/edit) verbatim in your question. Also don't spam tags please, c++ is certainly not relevant here.

Comment: Hint:  `int(input())`  tries to return an `int`, not a `tuple`.

Comment: When i enter three numbers this error pops up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/saura/PycharmProjects/Python/exercise.py", line 1, in <module>
    num1 , num2 ,num3 = int (input ( "enter three numbers ")).split(",")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,3,4'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: That's because `2,3,4` is not a valid integer.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Because you are trying to convert string with `,` to int and then splitting int.

Comment: There is no question here. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok but i tried to do it another way by removing int from first line and putting it in like this format ( int ( num1), int (num2),int (num3))

Comment: i have installed latest python 3 but pycharm wont let me use the newest string formatting  method so i had to use python 3.6 method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `int()` requires a single value.

You can use a list compression and literal string interpolation (*f-string*):

```
num1, num2, num3 = [int(x) for x in input("enter three numbers ").split(",") ]
print(f"average of three numbers is {(num1+num2+num3)/3} ")
```

The first line `[ ... ]` returns a list of integers, which is assigned to the tuple on the left (`num1, num2, num3`).  The f-string in the `print` does the calculation inside `{  }` and `format()` is not used.

f-strings require python 3.6 or later.

Here is an alternative using `map()` rather than the list comprehension and `format()` instead of an f-string:

```
num1, num2, num3 = map(int, input("enter three numbers ").split(","))
print( "average of three numbers is {}".format((num1+num2+num3)/3))
```

Comment: It works but why you used ----> for int (x) for x in input      Can you explain please i am new to python

Comment: That's called a *list comprehension*.  I could have used `map(int, ....)` instead.  See https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many mistakes, read this code:

```
num1 , num2 , num3 = map(int, input("enter three numbers:").split(","))
print ( " average of three numbers is {}".format((num1+num2+num3)/3))
```

Comment: Thank you sir.I am begginer thats why i made so many mistakes.Sorry but you have to bear with me. BTW this community is very helping :)

Comment: @rE_bOot That's all right, just read the code and try to figure out what you did wrong. :-)